# Is it a false security alert?

Tags: offset, imaging, malformed

I'm getting this alert:

```
Microsoft Kodak Imaging small offset malformed tiff-small endian
```

I scanned the affected system with an antivirus: no infection found. Is this a false IPS alert ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the alert is true. The only way to know for sure is to submit the file to the maker of the software giving the alert and ask them to verify.

Here an explanation of that alert:

> Kodak Image Viewer in Microsoft Windows 2000 SP4, and in some cases XP
> SP2 and Server 2003 SP1 and SP2, allows remote attackers to execute
> arbitrary code via crafted image files that trigger memory corruption,
> as demonstrated by a certain .tif (TIFF) file.

https://www.snort.org/rule_docs/1-34135